# How to list dependent packages (reverse dependencies) for a system I don't have installed?

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I know I can get a package's reverse dependency list with

```
apt-cache rdepends <pkg>
```

However, this shows dependencies on the system I run it on.

How could I find out dependent packages for a different distro (e.g. an old Debian Wheezy/Jessie) without installing it somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give `apt-cache` extra package sources after downloading them, and get it to ignore the installed package sources; for example for Jessie `amd64`:

```
wget http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
printf "" > /tmp/status
apt-cache -p /tmp/pkgcache -s /tmp/srccache -o Dir::State::Lists=/tmp -o Dir::State::Status=/tmp/status --with-source Packages.xz rdepends libevdev2
```

The various `/tmp`-based options instruct `apt-cache` to look for metadata files in `/tmp`; it won’t find any there, apart from the `status` file (or, at least, it shouldn’t — use another directory if necessary), so it will only use the information in the given `Packages.xz` file.

Comment: I believe https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60557 would be a valid approach as well.

Comment: @Quasímodo that involves changing the running system’s configuration, which I’d rather avoid unless really necessary, and it lists reverse dependencies outside the chosen release (for example on a Debian 10 system, with Jessie, it will list `libinput5` and `libinput10` as reverse dependencies of `libevdev2`).

Answer (score 1):

apt-rdepends --reverse (recursive reverse depends) also works:

```
wget http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
touch /tmp/status
apt-rdepends -o Dir::Cache::pkgcache=/tmp/pkgcache -o Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache=/tmp/srccache -o Dir::State::Lists=/tmp -o Dir::State::Status=/tmp/status -o APT::Sources::With=Packages.xz --reverse libevdev2
```

Comment: It’s IMO better to empty `/tmp/status` instead of touching it, just to ensure that there’s nothing there that might mess things up.